TypeScript Error: Implicitly has return type 'any' for Function with Recursive Call
So I have been trying to implement an Access and Refresh Token system for a while now.
I have had some success some failures. Some frustration. But overall I feel happy with my results.
I have come up with these API endpoints in my frontend to handle the refreshing (Which is not time-based but rather its supposed to be called on every action the user takes).
I have tried a similar approach in which I just do a react-query retry if the Access Token fails. I didn't really feel like that was the best approach so I came up with this recursive call.
This is the endpoints that the react-query will call
export const checkAccessToken = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URI}/api/auth/check-access-token`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("accessToken")}`,
    },
  });
  if (response.status === 401) {
    const result = await refreshAccessToken();
    if (!result) {
      throw new Error("Error while refreshing access token");
    }
    return checkAccessToken();
  }
  if (!response.ok) {
    throw new Error("Error while refreshing access Token");
  }
  const data = await response.json();
  return data;
};

And this is the function that gets called when the Access Token Fails
const refreshAccessToken = async () => {
  const response = await fetch(
    `${API_BASE_URI}/api/auth/refresh-access-token`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
    }
  );
  if (!response.ok) {
    return false;
  }
  const returnData = await response.json();
  localStorage.setItem("accessToken", returnData.accessToken);
  return true;
};

Which looks okay.. I guess I feel like its an improvement. But now the problem comes with typescript which gives me this error:

'checkAccessToken' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does
not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or
indirectly in one of its return expressions.ts(7023)

I have never encountered this particular error So I am lost on how to fix it. I would really appreaciate if anyone can help me or guide me in how to fix this error.
These are the backend Endpoints in case they are necesary:
//Check the access token endpoints
export const checkAccessToken = (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  const authHeaders = req.headers.authorization;
  if (!authHeaders || !authHeaders.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
    return res
      .status(401)
      .json({ message: "Invalid or missing Authorization Header" });
  }
  const token = authHeaders.split(" ")[1]; //Crea un array y lo separa quedando de lugar 1 el token
  try {
    const decoded = jwt.verify(
      token,
      process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY as string
    ) as AccessTokenType;
    if (!decoded) {
      return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
    }
    return res.status(200).json({ message: "User Verified" });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Error 500" });
  }
};

// Refresh token Endpoints
export const refreshAccessToken = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
      const token = req.cookies["refreshToken"];
      
      if (!token) {
        return res.status(401).json({ message: "Unauthorized" });
      }
    
      try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY as string) as RefreshTokenType;
    
        const cargoResult = await pool.query(
          "SELECT id_cargo FROM cargos_asignados WHERE id_empleado = $1 AND fecha_fin_asignacion IS NOT NULL",
          [decoded.id_empleado]
        );
    
        if (cargoResult.rows.length === 0) {
          return res.status(403).json({ message: "Forbidden: No active cargo found" });
        }
    
        const nameResult = await pool.query(
          "SELECT nombre FROM personas WHERE id_persona = $1",
          [decoded.id_empleado]
        );
    
        if (nameResult.rows.length === 0) {
          return res.status(404).json({ message: "Employee not found" });
        }
    
        const accessToken = jwt.sign(
          {
            id_empleado: decoded.id_empleado,
            cargo: cargoResult.rows[0].id_cargo,
            nombre: nameResult.rows[0].nombre,
          },
          process.env.JWT_SECRET_KEY as string,
          {
            expiresIn: "15m",
          }
        );
    
        res.status(200).json({ accessToken });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(500).json({ message: "Internal Server Error 500" });
      }
    };

And also the types used for both the access and refresh token:
export type AccessTokenType = {
    id_empleado: string;
    cargo: number;
    nombre: string;
}

export type RefreshTokenType = {
    id_empleado: string;
}

Thats basically all my relevant endpoints. I am still learning about Auth so any feedback or input is really appreciated! Thank you for your time!

have you tried adding a return type annotation as implied by the "error" message?


'checkAccessToken' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.(7023)

This error message tells you what the problem is, and how to fix it.

To explain let's simplify your code to this:
export const foo = () => {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    return foo();
  }
  return { test: 123 }
};

Which errors with:

'foo' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation and is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.(7023)

In this simplified example, Typescript tries to figure out what type this function returns and it sees two possible return types:

{ test: number }
ReturnType<typeof foo>

So, to know the return type of foo, it would need to know the return type of foo. This is circular. And cause is described in this part of the error:

'foo' [...] is referenced directly or indirectly in one of its return expressions.(7023)


Then in this part of the message:

'foo' implicitly has return type 'any' because it does not have a return type annotation [...]

Basically tells you that bold part were true, then this wouldn't be a problem. If you declare the return type for the function, then Typescript would not need to try to infer it for you from what the function returns.
So, add a function return type:
export const foo = (): { test: number } => {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    return foo();
  }
  return { test: 123 }
};
// no error

Now Typescript can see what foo returns without recursive traversal of your code.

So for you code, it looks like you have an async function, and it returns the result of JSON.parse() which, sadly, is any. Which makes the return type Promise<any>.
export const checkAccessToken = async (): Promise<any> => {
  //...
}

See playground

Final note: I usually don't recommend using any in your types, since it lets you do unsafe things. So if you can, replace that with the type that you know JSON.parse will return. Or even better, parse that data with a schema with tools like zod, typebox or arktype.
